# Doxygen generated Latex Files , Usage of LATEX_HEADER & INPUT tags

Tags: latex, doxygen, pdflatex

I tried to generate Latex Files with Doxygen. I used "INPUT" tag to get ".h" file and LATEX_HEADER to customise to my own HEADER. Problem is Integration of both Files. It is giving many Compilation errors IF i use both tags INPUT = /../../xxx.h file and LATEX_HEADER = ../../yyy.tex. If I use them individually Like only INPUT tag it is generating Doxygen Header and geting pdf without errors or If I use only LATEX_HEADER it is generating fine with my own HEADEr but not with both. Can any one suggest me anything.